# Output option not working in MJML

Tags: mjml, responsive-emails

I have written a gulp task to convert mjml file to html on change. Here is the code:

```
gulp.task('mjml:dev', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.mjmlWatch, {base: "./"})
        .pipe(mjml(mjmlEngine, {
            output: '.phtml'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Everything is working fine but I want the output extension to be `.phtml`. I use the output option but it is still generating the `.html` extension file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved it by installing the `gulp-dest` library using:

```
npm i gulp-dest --save
```

And after that just put another pipe that is replacing the extension of the file to `.phtml`.

```
gulp.task('mjml:dev', function () {
     return gulp.src(paths.mjmlWatch, {base: "./"})
            .pipe(mjml())
            .pipe(dest('./', {ext: '.phtml'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```